# is it possible to disable the auto compile when using latex workshop plugin in visual studio

Tags: latex-workshop

I am using the latex workshop plugin in visual studio to write a tex file, everytime I save the document the background task will auto build the document, I have already find the auto compile in latex workshop but failed, is there any way to disable the auto compile process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `settings.json` set:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run": "never"
```

According to the [wiki](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#latex-workshoplatexautobuildrun), the string `latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run` has three possible values: `never`, `onSave` and `onFileChange`(default).